# Cauchy gave 1st example of a Lie algebra in 1847 & exterior product in 1853‽

Tags: lie-algebras, math-history

I read in [PDF pg. 5 of this](http://www.i-b-r.org/docs/HMMC-1-02-26-08.pdf) that Cauchy gave the first example of a Lie algebra in 1847:

[image: image from book]

It also claims that he invented the exterior product in 1853.

Does anyone have references for this?

Comment: What  makes you think Santilli's pdf is reliable?

Comment: @user72694: He isn't the one who made this diagram. He merely reproduces it in the PDF. It comes from an award he received from the Estonian Academy of Sciences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding **Cauchy giving the first example of a Lie algebra**, the following might, although I'm not exactly sure, be the reference, from: Lie, Sophus, and Georg Scheffers. *Geometrie der berührungstransformationen*. Leipzig: B.J. Teubner, 1896, [p. 520](https://archive.org/stream/geoderberuhrung00liesrich#page/n537/mode/2up).:

> *Im Jahre 1847 betonte Cauchy in einer kurzen Note dass der Begriff: w-dimensionaler Raum bei vielen analytischen Untersuchungen, namentlich inder Zahlentheorie, förderlich sei.*
>
> ["In 1847 Cauchy stressed in a brief note that the term *n*-dimensional space in many analytical studies, especially in number theory, be beneficial."]

### Cauchy, «[Mémoire sur les lieux analytiques](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k29812/f885.image)». *Comptes rendus … de l’Académie des sciences* **24** (1847), [885-887](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k29812/f885.image).

---

Regarding **Cauchy giving the first example of an exterior product**, this seems to be the reference, from “[Grassmann, Hermann Günther](http://go.galegroup.com/ps/i.do?id=GALE%7CCX2830904887&v=2.1&it=r&p=GVRL&sw=w&asid=9c9d748bde7569a3acfd4e1190ea5d1b).” In *Complete Dictionary of Scientific Biography*, 15:192–199. Detroit: Charles Scribner’s Sons, 2008.:

### Cauchy, «[Sur les clefs algébriques](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k2993z/f74.image)». *Comptes rendus … de l’Académie des sciences* **36** (1853), [70-76](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k2993z/f74.image), [129-136](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k2993z/f133.image)

Comment: The quote from Sophus Lie only indicates that Cauchy recommended the use of the term "space", which can easily be interpreted as vector space rather than Lie algebra.  If this Santilli's source for first occurrence of Lie algebra, it is not very convincing.

Comment: @user72694: Yes, I agree, but do you agree the second source could be considered the "first example of an exterior product"?

Comment: @user72694: [Here is everything he wrote in 1847](https://archive.org/details/uvrescompltesda04natigoog); you can look, but I don't see any better reference than the one mentioned above.

Comment: Actually, what I linked in my previous comment was just the first part of what he wrote in 1847. [Here is the second part.](https://archive.org/details/uvrescompltesda11natigoog)

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure the last link I posted even contains his 1847 writings…